# How to return items in an iterable with an even index, in reverse

Tags: python, list, slice

Make a function named reverse_evens that accepts a single iterable as an argument. Return every item in the iterable with an even index...in reverse.

```
def reverse_evens(item):
    return item[::-2]
```

For example, with `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` as the input, the function would return `[5, 3, 1]`.

Comment: And whats the problem. Your function will do exactly what you said.

Comment: What's your code returning? What's your question?

Comment: @VaibhavVishal No; it doesn't: `[1,2,3,4][::-2] == [4,2]`, the items with odd indices.

Comment: Also, not all iterables are sliceable.

Comment: How do you want to define reversible: something that can be passed to `reversed`, or something you can iterate over in finite time?

Comment: A list is reversible in both senses; `range(...)` is reversible in the second sense, but `itertools.count(1)` is not reversible even in theory (where would the reversed sequence *start*?).

Answer (score 1):

This is two different operations:

- Select the even-numbered indices
- Reverse them

You can't do the first step backwards, since the index number is counted from the front.

```
def reverse_evens(item):
    return item[::2][::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
print([x for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][::2][::-1]])
```

Or try this for a larger code:

```
def reverse_evens(item):
  print(item)
  a = []
  for i in range(len(item)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
      a.append(item[i])
  return reversed(a)
print([x for x in reverse_evens([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be this (using list slicing):

```
def reverse_evens(item):
    return item[-1::-2]

print(reverse_evens([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Output:

```
[5, 3, 1]
```

The `[-1:-2]` means:

- Start from the last element (that is why we use `-1`).
- Count every two elements.